# Matlab: Transparent Object Detection

Tags: matlab, kinect, transparent, matlab-cvst

I'm trying to detect a transparent object (glass bottle) in an image.
The image is taken from the Kinect so there's rgb and depth images available.

I read from a literature that the boundary of an transparent object have 'unknown depth values' and I can use that as a boundary condition for detecting the object.

The problem is I cannot find that information from my depth file ie. the depth of the image only returns either zero or other values but never 'unknown'

I assume kinect represent 'unknown depth values' as zeros but this raises another problem:
there's a lot of zeros in the image ( ie. boundary etc) how do I know which zero is for the object?

Thanks alot!!

Comment: Can you post an sample of the image?

Comment: Also, consider migrating the question to dsp.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

You could try to detect the body of the transparent object rather than the border. The body should return values of whatever is behind it, but those  values will be noisier. Take a time-running sample and calculate a running standard deviation. Look for the region of the image that has larger errors than elsewhere. This is simpler if you have access to the raw data (libfreenect). If the data is converted to distance, then the error is a function of distance, so you need to detect regions that are noisier than other regions at that distance, not just regions that are noisier than elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you take a look at the following publication:

They were able to detect objects (such as water bottles and glasses). all undertaken in matlab.

Object localisation via action recognition.
J. Darby, B. Li, R. Cunningham and N. Costen.
ICPR, 2012.